# Looking to join 3 cells together but only if the 3 cells contain a value

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to TEXTJOIN 3 cells together but only if all three cells being joined have a value in them, the goal would be to just have values show up in column AL but I don't want a value that just says "ea"

Any help appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the column is blank. Replace your formula with:

```
=if(AI3="","",TEXTJOIN("", istext(Whatthefoxsay()), AI3," ", $AJ$1," ",AJ3," " , AK3))
```

Comment: Ah no dice unfortunately, says there are circular dependencies

Comment: @ColinMills the formula is working fine, you need to just put it in the cell that you showed in the picture, you must have pasted it in the wrong cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use `counta()`, like this in cell `AL3`:

`=if( counta(AI3:AK3) = 3, AI3 & " ea " & AJ3 & " " & AK3, iferror(1/0) )`

In the event "standardized amount" can optionally be left out, use `counta(AI3:AJ3) = 2` instead.